# How to plot diagram like a "#" in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, plot

I don't know how to plot diagram like a "#", anyone could give some tips?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are those lines supposed to be bent or straight? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I try the straight line through `tikzcd`, if I succeed I will paste my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can one draw such a graph? Sure. Are people here willing to do that for you? Well this will depend on their mood and also how new you are. Believe me, it is much more fun to do it on your own. Note also that there are 3d packages and nonlinear transformations etc. which can do a much better job if you have a concrete scenario and want more than just a cartoon.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\def\ldarray{{"i","i+1"}}
\def\luarray{{"k","k+\mu","k+1"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw[name path global=hor-\X-0] (0.1*\X,2*\X) to[bend left=12] ++ (5,1);}
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\draw[name path global=vert-\X-0] (2*\X-0.5,1+0.1*\X) to[bend left=15] ++ (0.3,7);}
\foreach \X [count=\XX starting from 0] in {1,2,3}
{\foreach \Y [count=\YY starting from 0] in {1,2}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\ld}{\ldarray[\YY]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lu}{\luarray[\XX]}
\path[name intersections={of=hor-\X-0 and vert-\Y-0,by=p\X\Y}] (p\X\Y)
node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,label=below right:$g_{\ld}^{\lu}$]{};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Follow your sample, i solve the problem.

Comment: @Ben You're welcome. I actually simplified the code quite a bit by getting rid of all the `\ifnum` stuff ...

Answer (score 7):

Follow marmot's sample,

Notice `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` and in the following code, define $Y= {1,2}$ is the Horizontal line, and $X={1,2,3}$ is the vert...

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw[name path global=hor-\X-0] (0.1*\X,2*\X) to[bend left=12] ++ (5,1);}
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\draw[name path global=vert-\X-0] (2*\X-0.5,1+0.1*\X) to[bend left=15] ++ (0.3,7);}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\foreach \Y in {1,2}
    {\ifnum\Y=1
        \def\ly{i}
        \else
        \def\ly{i+1}
        \fi
        \ifnum\X=1
        \def\ld{k} 
        \else
        \ifnum\X=2
        \def\ld{k+\mu}
        \else
        \def\ld{k+1}
        \fi
        \fi
        \path[name intersections={of=hor-\X-0 and vert-\Y-0,by=p\X\Y}] (p\X\Y)
        node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,label=below right:$g_{\ly}^{\ld}$]{};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]